# Adding another value to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this :

```
  $total= [20140124] => Array
    (
        [abc] => 0.19287878787879
        [total] => 38
        [revenue] => 1232
        [clicks] => 1110
        [score]=>100
    )

[20140123] => Array
    (
        [abc] => 0.32898148148148
        [total] => 28
        [revenue] => 1142
        [clicks] => 1022
        [score]=>200
    )
```

Now I am preparing another array and checking some conditions like the following:

```
foreach($total as $t){
    $new_array[] = array(
       "total"=>$t->abc;
       "another_value"=>$t->revenue/$t->clicks;
    );
    if(some_condition){
        $new_array[] = array("total_score"=>$t->clicks+$t->score); 
    }
}
```

What I need is an array like

```
$new_array = 

[0] => Array
        (
            [total] => total_value
            [another_value] => anopther_value
            [total_score] => total_score_value

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => total_value
            [another_value] => anopther_value
            [total_score] => total_score_value
        )
)
```

But I am not getting the total_score inserted to the 0th index. Instead the whole array is replaced with the values in the if condition. How can I get the total_score also with the other indexes ?

Comment: Why you use object notation ($t->abc) on arrays?

Comment: ha...that's a mistake anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
foreach($total as $t){
    $array_element = array();
    $array_element["total"] = $t["abc"];
    $array_element["another_value"] = $t["revenue"] / $t["clicks"];
    );
    if(some_condition){
        $array_element["total_score"] = $t["clicks"] + $t["score"]; 
    }
    $new_array[] = $array_element;
}
```

In your code you are adding an element to `$new_array` and *then* checking for that condition. So you are adding the next element, but not editing the first

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
foreach($total as $t){
    $data = array(
       'total'         => $t['abc'],
       'another_value' => $t['revenue'] / $t['clicks']
    );

    if(some_condition){
        $data['total_score'] = $t['clicks'] + $t['score']; 
    }
    $new_array[] = $data;
}
```

Comment: Actually both the answers are same. So I am accepting the first one. :) Thanks hsz

Comment: Not at all. @k102 uses `->` which are incorrect here. You are looping arrays, not objects, so you have to call array`s elements with `$array['key']` !

Comment: @hsz ok... shame on me

Comment: @k102 It was my mistake actually that I used '->' for array. Somehow it came in my mind and so used it. Anyway when I used k102 solution, I corrected it and used array.

Answer (score 1):

Its not getting inserted to 0th index because you are using $new_array[] which creates a new index each time it is called. You can use fixed index by incrementing a counter in your loop or by calling this once each iteration. Your counter solution will look as follows:

```
$count = 0;    
foreach($total as $t){
    $new_array[$count] = array(
       "total"=>$t->abc;
       "another_value"=>$t->revenue/$t->clicks;
    );
    if(some_condition){
        $new_array[$count] = array("total_score"=>$t->clicks+$t->score); 
    }
    $count++;
}
```